# When did the Republic start to fight droids?

Tags: star-wars, clones, droids, attack-of-the-clones

When did the droids or clones start fighting in Star Wars and why?

Comment: Fighters gonna fight...

Comment: The answer to this question is basically the whole Attack of the Clones movie. If you watched the movie, then you should know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time clones and droids fought each other was during the Battle of Geonosis. Obi-Wan, Anakin, and Padme were going to be executed on Geonosis. 212 Jedi went to their rescue, but were hugely outnumbered by the Separatist's secret droid army, and most of them were killed. But then the clones arrived, and managed to rescue the remaining Jedi, fighting the droids in the process.